# How can I refresh the authComponment::user cache

Tags: cakephp-2.3

Good afternoon,

I am used to get information about logged user, like this:

```
authComponent::user('email')
```

My problem is when the user is authentified and the change his e-mail address. It will always use the previous e-mail, until he logof and login again.

Is there a way to refresh AuthComponment cache, when the use change his profile?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

The information about the user it's stored in the Session. So you can access that and you can overwrite it when the profile changes.

Unless you have changed the key under which this information is stored the default is here:

`"Auth.User"`;

So, using the Session component you should write a value in the key `"Auth.User.email"` (if that is the name of the email field).

Of course you can dump and inspect the Session data under `"Auth.User"` to debug this and make it work.

Good luck! :)